# How to make loose Xaml content aware of custom controls

Tags: wpf, custom-controls, xamlreader

I have a loose XAML file...

```
<Style
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace"
    TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl}">
    <Setter Property="HoverOpacity" Value="1.0"/>
</Style>
```

... that I want to load at runtime.  When I do I get an exception stating, "Type reference cannot find public type named 'CustomControl'."  How can I make the loose XAML aware of my namespace?

I need to use `HoverOpacity` which is a dependency property of the `CustomControl`. Here is the code that I am currently using to load the XAML:

```
var resource = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Assets/HoverStyle.xaml"));

XamlReader.Load(resource.Stream);
```

BTW, I realize that the XAML is simple and I could just insert the `Style` in code, but this is a hello world XAML; its going to become a lot more complex, involving animations and such.

P.S. Another solution would be a way of either attaching a XAML file to a custom control derived from Panel (one that doesn't crash Visual Studio 2008) or a way of easily attaching triggers, data-triggers, entry-actions, and exit actions to custom controls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gosh darn it, I figured it out.  I needed to specify the assembly name with the namespace; like so:

```
<Style
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace;assembly=MyAssembly"
    TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl}">
    <Setter Property="HoverOpacity" Value="1.0"/>
</Style>
```

I'll give answer credit to anyone who could answer my "P.S." question within the next two days.  This whole situation seems a little wet, so I'd be really interested in alternatives.

Thanks :)